# CloudTrax - Authenticate Client

Tags: json, http, authentication, captiveportal

My question is somewhat related to the following question already posted:

[CloudTrax - Programmatically authenticate client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799775/cloudtrax-programmatically-authenticate-client)

I am extremely new to CloudTrax. I have read their documentation related to HTTP Authentication, which I understand for the most part, but I must admit that I'm uncertain where or how to send the "ACCEPT message". Does this need to be sent back to CloudTrax? Is there an API endpoint that I haven't found in their documentation?

If anybody could clarify this for me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Very late response, but hope it may help.

ACCEPT is a response given by a RADIUS. In other words, the RADIUS will decide whether to authenticate the client, based on the details (ie. username / passwords) sent.

The access point will keep track of who's authenticated and who's not, requesting access from the RADIUS when necessary.